# Clean font-size tag with Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I try to use Regex to clean `<font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif">` from

```
font-size:85%;
```

My Regex is `^font-size:(*);`

I mean I have to delete font-size tag completly.

Can someone help me pls?

Thank you!

Comment: Define "clean" - do you mean remove? Is this from a consistent source of HTML (i.e. all HTML pages are the same?). What is not working for you?

Comment: @Oded I mean to delete it completly.

Comment: Where does the HTML come from? Is the structure always the same?

Comment: Also - what is the issue? What's not working? "Can someone help me pls?" - sure. What with?

Comment: @Oded Well I guess it may be like font-size: 85%; or font-size: 85 %;  or even font-size : 85 % ;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several things with your current regex will cause it to fail:

```
^font-size:(*);
```

You are anchoring to the start of the line `^` - the attribute is not at the start of the line.

`*` on its own means nothing.

Change it to:

```
font-size: ?\d{1,2}%;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the regex you will need:

```
string html = @"<font style=""font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"">";
string pattern = @"font-size\s*?:.*?(;|(?=""|'|;))";
string cleanedHtml = Regex.Replace(html, pattern, string.Empty);
```

This regex will work even if the `font-size` is defined in `pt` or `em`, or if there is a different set of CSS styles defined (ie. `font-family` not specified). You can see the results [**here**](http://regexr.com?324im).

The explanation of the regex follows:

```
// font-size\s*?:.*?(;|(?="|'|;))
// 
// Match the characters “font-size” literally «font-size»
// Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s*?»
//    Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
// Match the character “:” literally «:»
// Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
//    Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
// Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(;|(?="|'|;))»
//    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «;»
//       Match the character “;” literally «;»
//    Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «(?="|'|;)»
//       Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?="|'|;)»
//          Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «"»
//             Match the character “"” literally «"»
//          Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «'»
//             Match the character “'” literally «'»
//          Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «;»
//             Match the character “;” literally «;»
```

Comment: Sorry your pattern string pattern = @"font-size\s*?:.*?(;|(?="|'|;))";  has some errors under Visual Studio...

Comment: @Terminador I didn't escape `"` character in the string. I've edited the answer now. It's important to receive our answers as a guidelines to solve your problem, so you should not be just copying the code and not trying to see what's wrong with it. We do not have time to fully test and debug our solutions.